# RANGE for non-adjected cells only excepts ";" instead of "," as delimiter now, No changes in sw/hw/code

Tags: vba, excel

**EDIT5:** The problem is solved. Not posted as answer, because I have no idea how. All I did: ->mess up excel by 2h loop, ->don't wana wait, kill excel via Taskmanager, ->restart PC (again)
...ofc I changed my whole project to ';' before -.-

Because I have still no Idea what happend I am still glad if anyone finds out what happend. I hate coding stuff I do not understand.

**[For main problem see edit3 pls]**

**Hy Comunity,**

I am coding a project. In an older, allready tested and working function some commands stopped working.
`RANGE("A1,B3"). ...` does not work any more,
`RANGE("A1;B3"). ...` does started working out of the blue.

First version is what I call *"English Notation"*,
the second version I call *"German Notation"* for they are also use in formulas of those languages (e.g. `=SUM(1,2,3)` vs `=SUMME(1;2;3)`).

I can confirm that the code WAS WORKING before, with the desired result.
Now it stoped working (runtimeerror '1004' - The method 'range' for the object '_global' failed [freely translated from german]).
Trial/Error brought me to the point were I realised that the second notation (using ";" instead of ",") that previously threw the same error now seems to work.

Any Idea? A simple matter of check a box in the options? I have no clue, and 2h+ of "helplines" (mostly MS itself) without result or even a clue kind of making me depressive. -.-

Thanks in advance!
greetings, jack

**EDIT1:**
The original code line:

```
Range( _
    Cells((longFirstRow + 2), (longFirstColumn + 0)).Address & "," & _
    Cells((longFirstRow + 3), (longFirstColumn + 2)).Resize(4, 1).Address & "," & _
    Cells((longFirstRow + 3), (longFirstColumn + 14)).Resize(4, 1).Address & "," & _
    Cells((longFirstRow + 3), (longFirstColumn + 25)).Resize(3, 1).Address & "," & _
    Cells((longFirstRow + 9), (longFirstColumn + 2)).Resize(16.1).Address & "," & _
    Cells((longFirstRow + 8), (longFirstColumn + 14)).Address & "," & _
    Cells((longFirstRow + 8), (longFirstColumn + 20)).Address & "," & _
    Cells((longFirstRow + 8), (longFirstColumn + 26)).Address) _
.NumberFormat = "@"
```

The resulted string would be something like: "$A$3,$C$4:$C$7,$O$4:$O$7,$Z$4:$Z$6,$C$10:$C$25,$O$9,$U$9,$AA$9"
I accept if you say it is unusual...may be. But it worked perfect.

**EDIT2:** Thanks for the quick replies. Even if there was no solution jet.

**EDIT3:** The VBA-Environment changed behavior. That is my main problem I want to understand how/why and change back. The RANGE command is only a symptom I can easily fix by replacing all ',' by ';' or by the great approach of SCOTT using union()

**EDIT4:** It seems I did not make one point clear before, sry for that: My OS is set to German, and always was. So is my Excel.

- `=SUMME(1;2;3)` - worked/works if manually inserted in cell at worksheet | did/does NOT work if used in vba (e.g.`.Formula = " ... "`)
- `=SUM(1,2,3)` - does/did NOT work if manually inserted in cell at worksheet | did/does work if used in vba (e.g.`.Formula = " ... "`)
- `RANGE("A1,B3")` - did work in vba, not any more
- `RANGE("A1;B3")` -
  does work in vba, DID NOT before

Comment: "Just change all "," to ";" then?" - Nice idea, lad. Thing is: I do not know why "correct notation" changed deffinition all of a sudden. What if it happens again? Change whole project every week? Two parallel version of the same project? + I just want to know! XD - Jack

Comment: + I tried adding al kind of stuff (like ThisWorkbook.Worksheets("..."). ), it all works with ";" and does not with ",", so I assume the solution is not "to add something before range"... plus it worked before, and I changed nothing in the whole Function. If more code is requested I will post it. Just tried to break it down to the error.

Comment: Are you trying to get the range between A1 and B3 or are you only wanting the two cells A1 and B3?

Comment: In the excample I want to select A1 AND B3, not A1 TO B3. The selection (see edit1) was to format all headers in a table.

Comment: See @danno161 answer, he/she provided the correct method in the second code line.

Comment: I am sorry, but he did not. His second method works just as his first. It selects a range. (e.g. Range("A1", "B3").Address returns "$A$1:$B$3", RANGE("A1,B3").address used to return "$A$1,$B$3" (though I have to replace ',' by ';' now at the command)

Answer (score 0):

When referencing a range, it should be done with a colon:

```
Range("A1:B3")
```

or if you are selecting individual cells as a range:

```
Range("A1","B3")
```

Edit (due to OP edit(s)): It seems as if your main issue is the difference between German and English formula formats. When using a German Excel file, the correct notation uses ";" rather than ",". So if you say your document was working previously with the delimiters being "," it is most likely a change in what language the file was opened in. If it was in English originally, the "," delimiter would work, but if it only now works with ";" then it would now appear that Excel's language settings were changed when reopening the file.

Edit 2: If language settings seem to be consistent, and you're on a Windows OS go to

**Control Panel** > **Change the date, time or number format** > **Additional Settings** > **List Separator** , check and see if the list separator is set to "," or ";

Comment: I think you missed one point: It worked before and, as intended, selected the intended range, including ranges and single cells. The original Code build a string at runtime and used that string for the range command (see my edit1 above).

Comment: see my comment on my question: your both options work exectly the same. Both select the range FROM A1 UP TO and including B3.

Comment: Both do not do the same thing, as you can see if you run each of these separately:
Sub selectrange()

ActiveSheet.Range("$A$1,$B$3").Select

End Sub

Sub selectrange2()

ActiveSheet.Range("$A$1:$B$3").Select

End Sub

Comment: You know that you use different syntax in your post than in your comment? Both methods in your post do the same. And the first method in your comment above: well, compare it to my aproach, and you find: This is exactly what I did, and what stopped working. ;)

Comment: To be honest, I do not get what you just said. I used a specific notation before (worked). If i work the EXACT SAME CODE now, it does not work. If I change the notation - to a one that did not work before - (','->';') it works. I am sorry, but I have no idea to be clearer. I know a thing or two about coding and and pc. And yes, I see, and tell you, symptoms of a problem. If I would have any idea HOW to solve it, I would have not created this account today. If you have an idea for "other ways of troubleshooting", pls tell me.

Comment: It was not at my radar that you can save an excel file not only as .xls, .xlsb, .xlsx,... but also with an associated language. TBH, I always assumed it would be interpreted when opend, using the program configuration of your installed version of excel (wich I did not change at all). Glad to hear that you can "hardcode"-ly link a language to a file. Pls tell me how, so I can associate English with my files again. :)

Comment: If you're on a windows OS go to **Control Panel** > **Change the date, time or number format** > **Additional Settings** > **List Separator** , check and see if it is set to "," or ";"

Comment: @IDontKnowJack did this fix it?

Comment: Sry, had no time to test the issue yet. Behavior occured several times since then, but a reeboot  seems to solve it so far. Have time preassure to finish the project. For I still want to understand this, I will test and update afterwards. Thanks for the help of you guys so far. :)

Answer (score 0):

You want to use the Union() function:

```
Union( _
Cells((longFirstRow + 2), (longFirstColumn + 0)), _
Cells((longFirstRow + 3), (longFirstColumn + 2)).Resize(4, 1), _
Cells((longFirstRow + 3), (longFirstColumn + 14)).Resize(4, 1), _
Cells((longFirstRow + 3), (longFirstColumn + 25)).Resize(3, 1), _
Cells((longFirstRow + 9), (longFirstColumn + 2)).Resize(16.1), _
Cells((longFirstRow + 8), (longFirstColumn + 14)), _
Cells((longFirstRow + 8), (longFirstColumn + 20)), _
Cells((longFirstRow + 8), (longFirstColumn + 26)))
```

This allows you to join a list of range objects.

This:

```
Sub hhh()
Dim t As Range
Dim longFirstRow
Dim longFirstColumn
longFirstRow = 1
longFirstColumn = 1
Set t = Union( _
    Cells((longFirstRow + 2), (longFirstColumn + 0)), _
    Cells((longFirstRow + 3), (longFirstColumn + 2)).Resize(4, 1), _
    Cells((longFirstRow + 3), (longFirstColumn + 14)).Resize(4, 1), _
    Cells((longFirstRow + 3), (longFirstColumn + 25)).Resize(3, 1), _
    Cells((longFirstRow + 9), (longFirstColumn + 2)).Resize(16.1), _
    Cells((longFirstRow + 8), (longFirstColumn + 14)), _
    Cells((longFirstRow + 8), (longFirstColumn + 20)), _
    Cells((longFirstRow + 8), (longFirstColumn + 26)))

    Debug.Print t.Address
End Sub
```

Returned:

```
$A$3,$C$4:$C$7,$O$4:$O$7,$Z$4:$Z$6,$C$10:$C$25,$O$9,$U$9,$AA$9
```

in the immediate window.

Comment: Well, I allways forget about the Union^^ The main problem still stands: How comes it suddelny stopped working? I tested it intensive. And it still works, if I replace all ',' by ';' in MY version using RANGE. How comes the VBA-Invironment seems to require the German delimiters all of a sudden? [cant upvote jet. Don't want to mark as answer, because it is only a workaround, not a solution for the real problem. Great for that "symptom" of mine though :) ]

Comment: @IDontKnowJack this is not a work around, it is the proper method to join multiple non sequential ranges.  As to why it suddenly shifted to not working I don't know, but it was never the proper way to do it, and If I had seen it in your code working or not I would have recommended changing it.

Comment: I see. ^^ Well, allways glad to get improvements (for I tought vba myself it can clearly need one or two). Still primary problem is why it suddenly changed behaviour (therefore workaround -> does not solve problem, but makes code work [even if better style than original atempt]). So IMO this should not be marked as answer. Still thanks for improving my coding style in vba. Much appreciated. :)

Comment: @IDontKnowJack I was not arguing for the points, I really do not care about them I am here to help. That being said, It must be a local settings thing, because it still works for me.  `Range("A3,B6")`. Address, returns `$A$3,$B$6`.  Also if I was going to use static addresses, using Range("") is how I would call it. If the address was not static I would use Union.  So if you type `? range("A3,B6").Address` in the immediate window you get an error?  Because I get one with `? range("A3;B6").Address`.  So it must have to do with the local settings.

Comment: Wasn't saying you are here for the points. And I am really glad for you and your kind (used this forum a lot in learning vba) and you just prooved me right for creating this account. :) Well, that was something I thought too, for ',' relates to english and ';' to german notation. Thing is I did not changed it, and have no Idea where it should be located. (notice: my excel itself was German the whole time. In worksheets I MUST use german formulas all time. System is set to german too. Any idea where I could find the mysterious option for changing vba-local-preferences or stuff?

Comment: @IDontKnowJack Sorry that is beyond my expertise, as I have never had the need to explore changing it.  I would suggest maybe googling how to change local settings in excel.  Also there are no bad feelings on my end.  I hope someone can answer your specific question.

Comment: Well, will google and test it next oportunity. ATM I am changing the project to "German" for I desperatly need it. xD Thanks anyways for your time and effort (and again, for improving my general code-style) :)